# Powershell Resource Websites

Tags: powershell

I'm new to powershell and have been looking for some good web sites for resources. Are there any web sites for learning powershell that you would recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Begin by the begining
[Windows PowershellOwner's manual](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee221100.aspx)
And : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc281945.aspx
[Cmdlet Reference for Windows Server 2008 R2](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee407531%28v=WS.10%29.aspx)

Subscribing to [PowerShell.com](http://powershell.com/cs/), you'll receive a good tips everyday, but also Expert Advice & Training, Forums, and Resources.

[PoshCode is a repository of PowerShell scripts](http://poshcode.org/) that are free for public use.

[Lot of ressources on PowerShell Community.](http://www.powershellcommunity.org/)

[The blog of Andy Shneider.](http://get-powershell.com/)

[The blog of Mike Pfeiffer](http://www.mikepfeiffer.net/)

**For French People** :

Laurent Dardenne wrote very good advanced articles :
http://laurent-dardenne.developpez.com/articles/Windows/PowerShell/Ressources/

The writter of one of the best french book on Powershell
http://www.powershell-scripting.com/

Answer (score 0):

I would say: http://www.powershellpro.com/

Answer (score 0):

I'll add Tobias Weltner's powershell.com site to the list
http://powershell.com/cs/blogs/ebookv2/default.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I have 3 resources bookmarked:

- [Windows PowerShell Survival Guide](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/windows-powershell-survival-guide.aspx)
- [PowerShell SIG of the North Texas PC Users Group](http://sites.google.com/site/powershellsig/)
- [Category:PowerShell](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Category%3aPowerShell)

Check them all, there is a lot of valuable resources including blogs to follow.

Answer (score 0):

I would say for question answers https://stackoverflow.com// is the best..
for tutorial we can refer any sites from below :

http://www.powershelltutorial.net/

http://powershelllive.com

http://powershellgroup.org/

---